# Python variables do not update

Tags: python, global-variables, variable-assignment

I have a very complicated formula, which I've simplified for the purpose of the question:

```
Position = θ_Zenith * θ_Azimuth
```

The Position formula will change over time, and thus I'd like to include it at the top of my .py script.

Python rejects this being at the top as there are no known values for θ_Zenith & θ_Azimuth.

If I place temporary values above the formula, such as:

```
θ_Zenith = 1 
θ_Azimuth = 1
```

I receive an error when they're updated on later line;

```
θ_Zenith = 2.5
```

and Print;

```
print(Position)
```

> I am still only getting a result for 1*1 = 1.

How can I get Python to update the variables within 'Position' formula prior to printing?

Comment: Write a *function* for the formula which you call again when you need to re-calculate it.

Comment: OK - that make sense, but can I place a function inside a function?  Lets say I have Position = Azimuth * Zenith. And Global_Position = Position * Xray... Do I need call function Posiiton and then call function Global_Position?

Comment: It's fairly unclear what that means exactly; please update your question with a concrete sample and what you are stuck on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you were writing in a form of, like:

```py
θ_Zenith = 1 
θ_Azimuth = 1

Position = θ_Zenith * θ_Azimuth
```

and, after that, re-assign the `θ_Zenith` with 2.5 and print the value like:

```py
θ_Zenith = 2.5
print(Position)
```

If that's it, it's simply because of the re-assignment afterwards will not update the mathematical function you have already assigned with those two variables. If you print the `id` of all those variables, it's easily to find that the variable `Position` remains unchanged. You have to re-assign the `Position` as well.

Once you have assigned variables with `float` or `int`, which are separate and immutable objects, variable names are references only and `id`s are the only fact. If you print the `id` of each `int` and `float` you've assigned (i.e. `id(1), id(2.5)`), you will suprising find that it is the same as variable one.

```py
θ_Zenith = 1 
θ_Azimuth = 1
print(id(θ_Zenith), id(θ_Azimuth), id(1))
# Out: 4498850032 4498850032 4498850032

Position = θ_Zenith * θ_Azimuth
print(id(Position), id(1)==id(Position))
# Out: 4498850032 True

θ_Zenith = 2.5
print(Position)
# Out: 1 

print(id(θ_Zenith), id(2.5))
# Out: 4499936368 4499936368
print(id(θ_Azimuth), id(Position), id(1))
# Out: 4498850032 4498850032 4498850032
# You may find that the id of 'θ_Zenith' is changed, but not the one of 'Position'


Position = θ_Zenith * θ_Azimuth # this will update Position after re-assignment
print(Position)
# Out: 2.5
```

However, this is too tedious as you have to update the value of variable `Position` every single time; write a function instead. Something like user @RainFlyWave suggested:

```py
def position(variable_a: float, variable_b: float) -> float:
    return variable_a * variable_b
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you evaluated first 'Position' variable and you're using it as an holder.
If you change on of the variables, you have to evaluate it again.
The best way to avoid these mistakes is actually to create a function, that will return value.

ex.

```
def position(variable_a: float, variable_b: float) -> float:
    return variable_a * variable_b
```

Comment: This seems like a great assistance. Thank you!

Comment: Can you elaborate as to what float ->  does in this example?

Comment: This is not nescessary, but it helps in case like help() function. When your code editor (IDE), tries to autocomplete some formula, this could be a great assistance. This just shows you, that this function takes two arguments that are floats, and returns float too. Here: https://peps.python.org/pep-0484/